# Javascript - Adding Class and Style Prescience

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I'm trying to make little progress indicators for a form that change depending on the page you are on. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to create the circle ID's, style them, and then just add a class list with one or two stylistic changes to show something different as a specific page was brought up.

When my function executes, the new class with the changes is being added -- the dom is proving that -- but, the style is not overtaking the original.

I've tried classList.Add, classList.toggle, className.add/Classname.toggle.  Nothing seems to work.

Why might that be?

```js
function nextPage()
{
 var step2 = document.getElementById("step2");
 
step2.classList.toggle("newClass");
 
};
```

```css
#step2
{
 height: 27px;
 width: 27px;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e9e9e9);
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: "";
 margin-left: 95.5px;
 float: left;
}

.newClass
{
 background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #8c66ff);
}
```

```html
<div id="step2"></div>

<br />

<p id="next" onclick="nextPage()">Next</p>
```

Comment: See [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules -- ID has higher specificity than a class so it gets priority.

Comment: Change `.newClass { ... }` to `#step2.newClass { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating CSS Specificity Value:

As we know, it was because simply using the class name by itself had a lower specificity value and was trumped by the other selector which targeted the unordered list with the ID value. The important words in that sentence were class and ID. CSS applies vastly different specificity weights to classes and IDs. In fact, an ID has infinitely more specificity value! That is, no amount of classes alone can outweigh an ID.
For more info https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

So, more specificity use Class aswell as IDs.
    !importent, also works but it note a good practice.
Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Your id `step2` will always override your class `newClass`.

Easiest solution is just to change `.newClass { ... }` to `#step2.newClass { ... }` in your CSS to make it more specific

```js
function nextPage()
{
 var step2 = document.getElementById("step2");
 
step2.classList.toggle("newClass");
 
};
```

```css
#step2
{
 height: 27px;
 width: 27px;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e9e9e9);
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: "";
 margin-left: 95.5px;
 float: left;
}

#step2.newClass
{
 background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #8c66ff);
}
```

```html
<div id="step2"></div>

<br />

<p id="next" onclick="nextPage()">Next</p>
```

Comment: "Your id `step2` will always override your class `newClass`." This is not true, even though it is **not recommended**, using `!important` will override `step2` properties. Also, multiple class / id and class selectors could make things harder to maintain. IMO the correct approach would be to either change his id `step2` selector to a class, or separate his `linear-gradient` into another class that can be overwritten by his `newClass` by cascade. You can still keep the id if it helps as a selector for his JS functions.